# How to get the uri in callback of onError from apollo-link-error?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I use apollo-link-error to handle graphql errors. I need to know the uri of the current link in the callback of onError. However, the signature of the callback is as follows:

function ({operation, response, graphQLErrors, networkError, forward})

It seems it is impossible to get the uri from these parameters. So do I miss something? Or do I need to use other tools to achieve this purpose?
In fact, I need to know the uri for retrying purpose (retry to request another server).

I config the client as follows,

```
var uriList = [uri1, uri2]
const customFetch = (uri, options) => {
    const dynamicURI = getOneURIFromURIList()
    return fetch(dynamicURI, options);
}
const errorLink = onError(({ networkError, operation, forward }) => {
    if (needRetry(networkError)) {
        // Here, if I know the URI of the terminating link, I can removed it
        // from the uriList, and customFetch will not choose it again.
        return forward(operation)
    }
})
const link = errorLink.concat(createHttpLink({ fetch: customFetch }))
```

Comment: Sharing your client configuration, including the links, would help in providing a more specific answer to your question. Without any sample code, it's hard to provide more than a generalized answer.

Comment: @DanielRearden Thanks for your kindly reply. I re-edited the question. While the process of re-editing, I found the `uri` parameter of customFetch may be what I want. Is it the URI of the previous call to `getOneURIFromURIList` when a retry happens? I haven't try it yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, after a test, I found the `uri` parameter of customFetch does not change, it is `/graphql` as default.

Comment: Edited my answer with an untested but feasible workaround for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request URL is not available as a parameter on the `onError` callback.

Clients only include a single [terminating link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/overview/#terminating-links) -- usually an `HttpLink` or `BatchHttpLink`. The only exception to this is when we use the `split` function to support both a `WebSocketLink` and another terminating link. All that to say your client will generally have a single `HttpLink` and that link will have a single URL for making requests -- i.e. you'll typically have just the one request URL *per client*. Unless you're using a custom link or an otherwise atypical setup, given a particular client you should already have access to this URL outside the context of the `onError` callback.

EDIT:

I would suggest a more traditional approach to load balancing rather than trying to do this client-side (for example, using an actual load balancer or implementing the functionality with [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)). This way, your client would only have one URL to use whether for the initial request or a retry and deciding which server to use for the request would be handled by the backend.

That said, you should be able to achieve what you're trying to do by utilizing context and the `split` function. Something like this should work:

```
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { split, from } from 'apollo-link'

const contextLink = setContext(() => ({
  // you could return something other than the URI here, like a number
  // we just need some value that's unique to each link
  targetURI: getOneURIFromURIList()
}))

const optionalHttpLink1 = split(
  (operation) => operation.getContext().targetURI === URI_1,
  createHttpLink({ uri: URI_1 })
)

const optionalHttpLink2 = split(
  (operation) => operation.getContext().targetURI === URI_2,
  createHttpLink({ uri: URI_2 })
)

const optionalHttpLink3 = split(
  (operation) => operation.getContext().targetURI === URI_3,
  createHttpLink({ uri: URI_3 })
)

const errorLink = onError(({ operation }) => {
  // call operation.getContext().targetURI to determine the URI used
})

const link = from([
  contextLink,
  optionalHttpLink1,
  optionalHttpLink2,
  optionalHttpLink3,
  errorLink,
])
```

You'll also want to make sure you drop the customFetch option for the above to work.

Also note that `split` takes a second link as an optional third parameter. So with two parameters, you specify the condition and a link to use if the condition is met. With three parameters, you specify a condition, a link to use if the condition is met *and* a link to use if the condition is not met. All that to say if you're only working with two URIs in the example above, you can use just one `split` instead of three:

```
const httpLink = split(
  (operation) => operation.getContext().targetURI === URI_1,
  createHttpLink({ uri: URI_1 }),
  createHttpLink({ uri: URI_2 })
)
```

If you have more than 2 URIs, you'll want one `split` per URI.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer really help me out of my problem. Following your guide, I put the targetURI into the context (use something like `contextLink` in your code) . I still use `customFetch` (showing in my code) in which I can get the failed targetURL out of the context, and choose a new one to retry the request.